# Multiplication between a normal subgroup and an arbitrary subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Given $G$ a group. $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$, and $H$ an arbitrary subgroup of $G$. Prove that $G=NH$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I have to prove that $NH=HN$. But for every $h\in H$ we have that $Nh=hN$ then $NH=\bigcup_{h\in H}Nh=\bigcup_{h\in H}hN=HN$ then $NH=HN$ which implies that $NH$ is a subgroup of $G$

Is this  correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. But you might spell out how you arrived to the point: 'you have to prove $NH=HN$'.

Comment: Do you mean to prove the equality $NH=\bigcup_{h\in H} Nh$?

Comment: No. I mean, you originally needed $NHNH\subseteq NH$ and $(NH)^{-1}\subseteq NH$, and that those reduce to proving $NH=HN$.

Comment: It looks fine to me, assuming that you knew a priori that for $NH$ to be a subgroup it is necessary and sufficient to have $NH = HN.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. 
But you might spell out how you arrived to the point: 'you have to prove $NH=HN$'.